# Java, проблема с прохождением вложенного цикла

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
Что-то запарился с вложенными циклами, как сделать их правильно...

Есть 3 List и переменная

```
List<File>totalFileList  //Список всех файлов, которые нужно обработать
List<File>overLimitList  //Список файлов, которые нужно исключить из обработки
List<Cont>ContainersList //Список объектов класса Cont
long limitSize           //устанавливает лимит объема файла (в байтах)
```

В свою очередь класс Cont имеет следующие поля:

```
List<File>filesOnCont    //Список файлов внутри класса
long contSize            //тут сохраняется размер файлов(в байтах), добавленных в filesOnCont
```

плюс сеттеры и геттеры для них

---

Написал код, который обрабатывает это все дело, но он делает только проход по содержимому *первого* контейнера в списке ContainersList. Пробовал другие варианты - но в итоге все только хуже, а ведь точно упустил какую-то деталь. :)

Вероятно для подобных случаев есть более удобные способы решения, но пока на ум только такой пришел..и то неверный)

Заранее благодарен за ответ

---

```
for (int f = 0; f < totalFileList.size(); f++) {                                 
        long fileSize = totalFileList.get(f).length();

        if (limitSize == fileSize) {                                                    //Если размер файла равен лимиту, сразу создаем новый контейнер
            createNewContainer(totalFileList, ContainersList, f);
        }
        else if (fileSize > limitSize) {                                                //Если размер файла больше лимита, добавляем файл в список с исключениями                         
            overLimitList.add(totalFileList.get(f));                               
        }
        else if (fileSize < limitSize) {                                                //Если размер файла меньше лимита 
            if (ContainersList.isEmpty()) {                                               // проверяем, если список контейнеров пуст
                createNewContainer(totalFileList, ContainersList, f);                     //тогда сразу создаем новый контейнер и кладем туда файл
            }
            else if (!ContainersList.isEmpty()) {                                         //Если список контейнеров уже содержит контейнеры
                for (int c = 0; c < ContainersList.size(); c++) {                         // !!!!! Вот тут проходит только по c = 0; другие даже не рассматривает !!!

                    if (limitSize >= ContainersList.get(c).getcontSize() + totalFileList.get(f).length()) {      //Если лимит в контейнере еще не превышен, и текущий файл способен туда попасть
                        ContainersList.get(c).addFileToContFileList(ContainersList.get(c).getcontFileList(), totalFileList.get(f));     //впихиваем в текущий контейнер этот файл
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (limitSize < ContainersList.get(c).getcontSize() + totalFileList.get(f).length()) {  //Если текущий файл не влезает в существующие контейнеры
                        createNewContainer(totalFileList, ContainersList, f);             //создаем новый контейнер
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

}

---

Также тут упоминается метод createNewContainer

```
public static void createNewContainer (List<File> totalFileList, List<Cont> ContainersList, int index) {  

    Cont cont = new Cont();
    cont.getcontFileList().add(totalFileList.get(index));
    cont.setcontSize(cont.getcontSize() + totalFileList.get(index).length());

}
```

и метод addFileToContFileList из класса Cont

```
public void addFileToContFileList (List<File> contFileList, File file) {  //метод из класса Cont
    contFileList.add(file);
    setcontSize(contSize + file.length());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для начала назовите правильно переменные - `ContainersList` должно быть с маленькой буквы, избавьтесь от дублирования и упростите методы вынеся куски логики в подметоды, а то смотреть страшно:

```
public static void createNewContainer (List<File> totalFileList, List<Cont> ContainersList, File file) {
    Cont cont = new Cont();
    cont.getcontFileList().add(file);
    cont.setcontSize(cont.getcontSize() + file.length());
}

void someMethod() {
    for (File file : totalFileList) {
        long fileSize = file.length();

        if (fileSize == limitSize) {
            createNewContainer(totalFileList, containersList, file);
        } else if (fileSize > limitSize) {
            overLimitList.add(file);
        } else {
            fileLessLimit(file);
        }
    }
}

private void fileLessLimit(File file) {
    if (containersList.isEmpty()) {
        createNewContainer(totalFileList, containersList, file);
    } else {
        for (int c = 0; c < containersList.size(); c++) { // !!!!! Вот тут проходит только по c = 0; другие даже не рассматривает !!!
            if (limitSize >= containersList.get(c).getcontSize() + file.length()) {
                containersList.get(c).addFileToContFileList(containersList.get(c).getcontFileList(), file);
                break;
            } else {
                createNewContainer(totalFileList, containersList, file);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь по сути вопроса: 
Нижний цикл for может выполниться только 1 раз всего по 2 причинам:

1) в `containersList` только 1 элемент

**2) выполнился `break` который прервал цикл, а у вас их там целых 2, причем один из них выполнится в любом случае.**

Comment: спасибо, поправил у себя код. Если я убираю оба break, то у меня программа проваливается в бесконечный цикл. С брейками создает много контейнеров, но проверяет и заполняет файлами только первый из них. Который обозначается с = 0. Если убираю первый брейк, то он заполняет и следующие, но неккоректно, может несколько одних  и тех же файлов добавить во все контейнеры. Не могу понять, точно же упустил что-то простое.. но не соображу что.

Answer (score 1):

А где у тебя объявление `p` и где ты ее инкриментишь? Может быть ты опечатался и тебе надо писать `ContainersList.get(с).getcontSize()` вместо `ContainersList.get(p).getcontSize()` ?

И еще. Вместо `for (int f = 0; f < totalFileList.size(); f++) {` используй `for(File file : totalFileList)` - так удобней и читабельней

Comment: да, там *c* вместо *p*